# Count by Column Name or by Fixed Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

General question about performance of SQL Server, requiring knowledge of how processing of COUNT() actually works on rows of a dataset.

In my youth, I would write a simple query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DEAL_ID) FROM DEAL WHERE DEAL_DATE_FIRST_SIGNED IS NOT NULL
```

Years ago, I realized the column name was unimportant and (at worst) perhaps conveyed information that was not semantic, since it's irrelevant to the count and could cause confusion. I began writing COUNT() columns like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM DEAL WHERE DEAL_DATE_FIRST_SIGNED IS NOT NULL
```

I could also use any literal of course like:

```
SELECT COUNT('x') FROM DEAL WHERE DEAL_DATE_FIRST_SIGNED IS NOT NULL
```

I guess technically less bytes and shorter SQL queries is slightly better in terms of bandwidth but does anyone have an answer on which is actually faster/better, based on how SQL Server really puts this together?

In other words, is using an actual column bad for any reason whatsoever? For example, would SQL Server fetch the value of that column even though it's simply being used in a COUNT()?

I've been told that SQL Server does not look up the column but I can't be sure of this and I decided not to take the risks.

Really only asking about versions of SQL Server here but any answer that applies to other database systems would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an actual column strongly suggests to SQL compiler that the column should be read.  In fact:

```
count(<column>)
```

is different from:

```
count(1)
count('x')
count(*)
```

because the column is checked to be sure there is no `NULL` value.  I think SQL Server is smart enough to take `NOT NULL` constraints into account and not read the column.  But, if there is not such a constraint, the column must be read.

The other three are all functionally equivalent.  However, `COUNT(*)` is standard SQL and predominant.  I should note that `SUM(1)` is almost exactly the same thing, except it will return `NULL` instead of `0` if there are no matches.

Comment: I've often wondered about COUNT(*) for similar reasons. I've had a decidedly nightmare concern that SQL would return all columns and evaluate them for NULL. But you're saying that's not the case?

Comment: @Nick . . . Absolute not.  It counts the rows.  It will use an index if available.  And in some databases (but not SQL Server), it will actually just use metadata.